# Confusion over the Magento 2 Mobile Breakpoint 767px, 768px?

Tags: magento2, css, mobile

I've just confused myself here testing an iPad Mini which seems to be 768px. This was displaying desktop in older versions and now on an update is showing mobile i've noticed some styles were not correct so i've read dev docs and checked some demos online how they behaved and see what is supposed to be happening.

Dev docs states that "Breakpoints are used in the CSS code to set up the screen width at which the design switches from the mobile to the desktop version." and that the mobile breakpoint in Luma and Blank are 768px "@screen__m: 768px (in the Blank and Luma themes, this breakpoint switches between mobile and desktop views)"

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/responsive-web-design/rwd_css.html

**MagePlaza 2.4.5 Demo**

This seems to break at 769? so mobile on an iPad Mini at 768px.

https://magento-demo.mageplaza.com/?_gl=1*6n3fs2*_gcl_au*MTAxNjY2NjA5MS4xNjg5MTYwNTYx

**MageBit 2.4.? Demo**

Not entirely sure here on the version but breaks at 768 so desktop on an Ipad at 768px.

https://magento2-demo.magebit.com/

Not sure really what the intention is here anymore but feel according to docs the iPad mini (or 768px devices) should be desktop so unsure which way to fix. Seeming to me more difficult to fix to be desktop than fix the slight changes to keep mobile at 768px but feel the latter is incorrect according to docs. Both the Blank and Luma themes however are mobile at 768px.

Is anyone else noticing inconsistencies here in the core code for this breakpoint?

e.g. styles-m.css:12081

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px)
.navigation, .breadcrumbs, .page-header .header.panel, .header.content, .footer.content, .page-main, .page-wrapper > .widget, .page-wrapper > .page-bottom, .block.category.event, .top-container {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

Surely if "design switches from the mobile to the desktop version." at "768px" the max width of mobile / tablet styles here should be 767px.

Answer (score 1):

A change was made in Magento 2.4.4 (a year ago) that increase the max width for the mobile view to **768px** from **767px** in earlier versions. You can check the related commit: https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/04012ba8e939377c626fb853e75794e093173a68

If you want to revert this change, you can revert the change from the above commit.

Mageplaza demo using Magento 2.4.5-p1: the max width for the mobile view is 768px.
Magebit demo using Magento 2.4.3: the max width for the mobile view is 767px.

Comment: Thanks, is quite a large change is this definately intentional?

Comment: Seems to be a commit relating to page builder, surely there should be some kind of discussion about moving the whole desktop mobile breakpoint goal posts here. It doesn't line up with all other web design best practise that the tablet view now starts a pixel later than rest of my theme / bootstrap etc

Comment: As you can see from the commit, there is an internal ticket (ACP2E-169) for the internal team, which I do not have access to this resource. However, the commit message indicated the page builder image for the mobile view issue (perhaps it relates to https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/34551 issue).

Comment: In the release notes for version 2.4.4, there is some related info: "View breakpoints are now consistent across Magento Open Source." and "Images added using Page Builder are no longer duplicated on the storefront when displayed with a browser window width of 768px. Previously, with this browser window width, the application Open Source duplicated images on the storefront by displaying both the mobile and desktop version of images.". You can check it here https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/release/notes/magento-open-source/2-4-4.html?lang=en

Comment: Yea still don't seem right, what do you actually think? In my opinion this is wrong we should be "Small Desktop/Tablet" here for 768-1023 in my opinion I've fixed my store now but surely we shouldn't have to.

Comment: I've thought about this today and raised issue here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/37753 as don't think we should be mobile here, think the answer to this question would be "No this is a core bug, you are using a tablet (albeit smallest tablet) but should render 768px tablet view.

Comment: I'm not sure, but this change impacts many stores that have customized the default menu styling for the `@screen-m` break point. Let's wait for the response from the community and Magento (Adobe Commerce) core team.